# Get Seconds from midnight UTC

Tags: javascript, date

I simply need the number of seconds from the midnight of the present day.

It's a labyrinth of JS `Date` methods I can't untangle from.

I already searched for an off-the-shelf snippet. I tried this but it returns local time, not UTC:

```
let date = new Date(),
    d = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(),
        date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(),
        date.getUTCSeconds())),
    e = new Date(d),
    secsSinceMidnight = Math.floor((e - d.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)) / 1000);
```

Comment: Please post your attempts.

Comment: Here's my latest attempt (post updated).

Comment: Running that in node works for me. Currently returning ~5500, which is about an hour and a half (it's currently ~01:30 UTC).

Comment: It yields 16466 on my computer now. Fine, I incorrectly assumed this KVM instance had an adjusted hw clock

Answer (score 1):

I think you had the right idea, but got lost in the implementation. Your assignment to *d* is just a very long winded way of creating a copy of *date* that is equivalent to the assignment to *e*.

To get "seconds from UTC midnight", create a Date for now and subtract it from a copy that has the UTC hours set to 00:00:00.000.

```js
function secsSinceUTCMidnight() {
  var d = new Date();
  var c = new Date(+d);
  return (d - c.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)) / 1000;
}

console.log('Seconds since UTC midnight: ' + 
secsSinceUTCMidnight().toLocaleString() + '\n' + new Date().toISOString());
```